# Does "Every set of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable" imply some weakened LEM?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, lebesgue-measure, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I would like to know if the Reverse Mathematics has a conclusion for this axiom ($\text{LM}$:Every set of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable).

I have tried to translate this axiom into a halting problem like $\text{LPO}$, but without success.

Comment: I asked a related problem on MO a while ago, and am still interested. But could you first clarify your base theory? I assume it's something like intuitionistic ZF or weaker

Comment: @Lxm If, like me, you are just looking for the halting problem form of this axiom (LM), or want to find an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $WF_\alpha\models Con(IZF+LM)$, then IZF is enough. If you want to do reverse mathematical research, then you need to use KP as the ground model. If you're searching for a constructive interpretation of the LM, then you need MLTT(Martin-Löf Type Theory). If you are prepared to work on a constructive model of the real analysis, just use Cubical Agda.

Comment: @Lxm I doubt that neither here nor MO can solve our problem. Probably need to move the problem to cs.stackexchange, cstheory.stackexchange or proofassistants.stackexchange.

Comment: First, how do you define the Lebesgue measurability in a constructive manner? The standard definition of Lebesgue measurability relies on Borel sets, whose formulation heavily relies on LEM. There are some ways to avoid this, like, using the formulation by Bishop. Your question could be meaningless unless you provide a formulation of Lebesgue measurability over the background theory you want to analyze.

Comment: Second, your comment suggests your understanding of logic needs improvement. What is $\mathsf{WF}_\alpha$? $\mathsf{IZF+LEM}$ is $\mathsf{ZF}$, so why do you use $\mathsf{IZF+LEM}$? Also, you mixed up models with theories, which are completely different notions. And, what is the relationship between LEM and the halting problem?

Comment: (By the way, I bet if we formulate Lebesgue measurability correctly, then it does not imply anything about LEM, although it may imply the consistency of $\mathsf{ZF}$ with an inaccessible.)

Comment: @HanulJeon 1)Yes, I hope https://github.com/math-comp/analysis/blob/master/theories/lebesgue_measure.v can meet the requirements. 2)This is just the application of the reflection theorem. If a theory is consistent, then it satisfies in the proper initial segment of the Well-founded Universe (in a suitable metatheory) $WF_\alpha$. 3) $\mathsf{LM}$ means "$\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable" not $\mathsf{LEM}$ 4) When I say halting problem I'm thinking $\mathsf{LPO}$. it doesn't make sense to use the full $\mathsf{LEM}$.

Comment: 1. I have not checked what you linked in detail, but it seems to me that it works over the classical logic, so it does not fit with what you asked. 2. I have not heard your reflection theorem, and it does not make sense over $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Could you provide any reference that mentions your reflection theorem? 3. Okay, I got it. 4. How can we say $\mathsf{LPO}$ as a halting problem? They might have some association, but they are clearly different, and you should not conflate them unless you justify why confusing them is okay.

Comment: @HanulJeon 1. You are right, math-comp/analysis has LEM, constructive Lebesgue measurable should not be implemented on proof assistants yet. 2.h ttps://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Reflecting#reflection-theorem 3. The halting problem is just a thought that allows me to think about whether Axiom LM violates the principles of constructionism. I now think it might be better to just use forcing. Of course this needs a definition for constructive Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: I still don't understand why you referred to the reflection principle: it is not known that it is provable over $\mathsf{IZF}$ (conjectured it is independent of $\mathsf{IZF}$.) Furthermore, even $\mathsf{ZF}$ does not prove the existence of $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models \mathsf{ZF}$ by the incompleteness theorem.